# Go, passing data to channel

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I have an issue. Here is example: https://play.golang.org/p/QSWY2INQuSE

```
func Avg(c chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    c <- "test"
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    c := make(chan string)

    timer1 := time.NewTicker(5 * time.Second)

    for {
        select {
        case <-timer1.C:
            wg.Add(1)
            go Avg(c, &wg)
            wg.Wait()
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(<-c)
}
```

Why data does not reach `fmt.Println(<-c)`

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you have an endless `for`, so the last `fmt.Println()` statement is never reached.

You have to break out of the loop if you want the last `fmt.Println()` statement to ever execute, for example:

```
loop:
    for {
        select {
        case <-timer1.C:
            wg.Add(1)
            go Avg(c, &wg)
            wg.Wait()
            break loop
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(<-c)
```

Note that you have to use a label, else the `break` would only break out of the `select` statement (and not from the `for` loop).

Also note that this alone won't work, as the channel is unbuffered, and thus `Avg()` will be blocked forever, trying to send a value on `c` while noone is ever trying to receive from it.

This simple example can be made working if you create the channel to be buffered:

```
c := make(chan string, 1) // Buffer for 1 value
```

Now it works and prints (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/05QvPdbWRui)):

```
test
```

Comment: Hey but in this case will brake and ticker will not be triggered every second as main function exited. How to use that ticker will be triggered every second?

Comment: @MihaZoubek If you don't want to exit after the first tick, then obviously don't "break" out of the loop. But then you will need (another) goroutine to "drain" the `c` channel concurrently, else without receiving from it the 2nd send on it would block forever.